# "Ребенок" и "дети"

Tags: этимология

Почему и как так вышло, что в русском языке один - ребенок, а много - дети? Почему настолько разные слова?

Comment: Не ребята ли множественное от ребёнок...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое явление при формообразовании называется супплетивизм основ. Таких случаев достаточно много: хороший - лучше, идти - шел, человек - люди и т. д.

Исторически конкурировали разные слова с одинаковым значением. От одного слова в результате осталась одна форма, от второго - другая.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально это были разные слова. Ребенок-ребята и Дитя-дети.
Обе пары древнейшие, индоевропейские, но первая, судя по всему, означала человеческого ребёнка, вторая - дитёныша вообще. Впоследствии "ребёнок" стало употребляться преимущетвенно для указания возраста, "дитя" - принадлежности родителям. 
Но во множественном числе указание семейных отношений было более актуальным, особенно для указания на детей разного возраста. Отсюда уже недалеко до развития современных значений. Во всяком случае - как версия.

Answer (score -2):

Русское слово «ребёнок» происходит от слова «ревёт». После рождения дитя плачет - ревёт. Естественно применение к своему дитя уменьшительно-ласкательных форм: «ревёнок», «ревёночек» с постепенным обретением формы «ребёнок», «ребёночек». Это чисто русское происхождение слова, не встречающееся в других славянских языках.

Слово «дитя» и его множественная форма «дети» также имеет естественное происхождение от धे (дэхти) общего предка с санскритским словом धयति (даяти), имевшим значение «сосать»[1]. После рождения ребёнок плачет и сосёт грудь матери - что и отражалось в первоначальном смысле слова «дети».

↑ Кочергина В.А. Санскритско-русский словарь: около 30 000 слов. — Русский язык. — Москва, 1987. — С. 944. — ISBN 5-902766-05-2.

Кстати, в санскрите встречается слово रेभति (ребхати), обозначающее кричать и реветь. От глагола ребхати происходит существительное रेभ (ребха), то есть, рёва, и причастие रेभण (ребхана), то есть, ревущий.

Хочу сразу обратить внимание, что в этимологических словарях по поводу слова ребёнок творится что-то несуразное. Слову "ребёнок" приписали множественную форму "дети", хотя слову "дети" соответствует слово "дитя". А в этимологическом словаре немца Фасмера происхождение "ребёнок" насильно выковыривается от слова "раб". Несмотря на критику словаря Фасмера, видимо никто из лингвистов не захотел возится с его трудом. Потому его, мягко говоря, измышления считаются классическими.

Comment: В и Б в русском языке сильно отличаются друг от друга и переход одного в другой сомнителен. Это подтверждается и тем, что в остальных славянских языках слово "ре**в*"*енок отсутствует.

Comment: Почему «сразу обратить внимание» захотелось в последнем абзаце?

Comment: Потому что сладкое блюдо - поругать немца - автор оставил на закуску.